# finding the BigO of an algorithm

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I am trying to learn about bigO notation and time complexity of algorithms. I am having a hard time verifying whether my calculations are correct for the following algorithm:

```
def f(n):
    i = 0
    n = n[0]
    while i < n:
        j = n
        while j > 1:
            m = i + j
            print(m, " ", i)
            j = j // 2
        i = i + 1
```

I am calculating the algorithm to have a bigO of O(1).
Is there an easy way to calculate the bigO of an algorithm without having to work it out?

Comment: Hello! This question isn't really answerable unless you specify what the time-complexity is being measured against. Are you measuring with respect the length of `n`, the value of `n[0]`, or something else? Please share your work so far (with an [edit]), and explain how you arrived at an upper bound of `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the big-O by counting / calculating the total number of "processes" of "cycles" your algorithm would do in a worst-case scenario (there are different notations for average and best-case scenarios).

So if you've got code that does

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    doSomething();
}
```

You take a worst-case number of `n` cycles to complete this piece of code, because the most amount of times you could possibly loop over it would be `n` times. The big-O of this would be `O(n)`.

Now if you've got a piece of code that does

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

The big-O of this would be `O(n*k)`, because you loop over the code `n` times, but inside that you loop another `k` times, executing the `k`-loop `n` times.

Excuse me for using C-style code, but my Python is very rusty.